# Как поставить координаты для фиксированного объекта (меню) css?

Tags: html, javascript, css

У меня есть менюшка, у которой значение `position: fixed;`. Она  при скроллинге болтается то вертикально, то горизонтально, то есть по оси (X;-X;Y;-Y). А мне нужно, чтоб фиксация была только вертикально, по оси  (Y;-Y).

Comment: Как это болтается то вертикально, то горизонтально? Если у нее position: fixed она должна быть прибита к одному месту на экране по всем осям.

Comment: как это должно выглядеть, дайте взглянуть...

Comment: Вы этого хотите? http://jsfiddle.net/07u3b9w4/1/

Comment: ВОТ!http://otvet.mail.ru/question/173168523
Здесь есть скриншот!

Comment: (LinnTroll) Объект то скролится по горизонтали и вертикали! А мне нужно! ТОЛЬКО ВЕРТИКАЛЬ!

Answer (score 1):

Вам просто необходимо указать координаты точки привязки, примерно так:

```
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
```

Такое позиционирование предполагает, что координаты меню будут задаваться относительно окна браузера. В данном случае-сверху, слева. Но думаю, Вам просто необходимо почитать про [многоколоночную вёрстку](http://info-line.net/videos/11-videourok-kursa-po-css-blochnaya-verstka-mnogokolonochnogo-sajta)...)). Тогда то, что Вы задумали реализовать, окажется куда проще, чем кажется... То есть меню просто будет в левом [сайдбаре](http://innova-media.ru/news/2055/) и привязано к точке так: `position:fixed; top:0px;`.

Вот Вам, кстати, [генератор шаблонов](http://csstemplater.com/) для сайта, попробуйте разобраться.

Comment: Меню просто сдвинулось точно в  угол и все, а скролится и вертикально, и горизонтально!

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо сделать отдельную колонку для меню (сайдбар), после задать для него `position:relative;`, для самого меню - `position:fixed;`. 
Далее позиционировать одно относительно другого.